# What does income inclusive or exclusive of super mean?

Tags: australia, employment, superannuation

In Australia when a job add says the income is inclusive or exclusive of super what does that mean?

e.g.  What is the difference between a job that says 55K inclusive of super vs 55K exclusive of super?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Superannuation basics](https://www.ato.gov.au/general/other-languages/in-detail/information-in-other-languages/your-superannuation-basics/)

> Superannuation, or 'super', is money put aside by your employer over your working life for you to live on when you retire from work.
>
> ...
>
> Your employer is required to pay a minimum amount based on the current super guarantee rate of your ordinary time earnings into super. This is set to gradually rise over the coming years.

[At the time of writing the superannuation rate](https://www.ato.gov.au/rates/key-superannuation-rates-and-thresholds/?page=22#Super_guarantee_percentage) is 10%

$55k inclusive of super means your annual salary is $50k and $5k will be paid into your superannuation account.

$55k plus super means your annual salary is $55k and $5.5k will be paid into your superannuation account.

Answer (score 1):

Super is short for [superannuation](https://www.ato.gov.au/Individuals/Super/).

This is a compulsory retirement fund that your employer must contribute to. Most employment in Australia will result in your employer paying super, although there are exceptions.

Currently the rate is 10%. So if the salary is exclusive of super then 10% of that amount will be paid to your retirement account rather than you receiving it to spend each month. On the other hand if it's inclusive of super then that is what you get after super has been paid by your employer.